# Alignment of the button in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have the following code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

section {
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
}

/*=====================*/
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox:after, .checkbox:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  -webkit-font-kerning: auto;
          font-kerning: auto;
  font-language-override: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-synthesis: weight style;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
.checkbox label {
  width: 90px;
  height: 42px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 46px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox input:hover + label:after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-1 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #376fcb;
}
.model-1 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4285F4;
}

.model-2 .checkbox label {
  width: 75px;
}
.model-2 .checkbox label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-2 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-2 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 35px;
}

.model-3 .checkbox label {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 38px;
}
.model-3 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #bbb;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.model-3 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: 55px;
}

.model-4 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 25px;
  width: 75px;
}
.model-4 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  top: -8px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}
.model-4 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #77C2BB;
}
.model-4 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #009688;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-5 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 15px;
  width: 85px;
}
.model-5 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  top: -12px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:hover + label:after {
  transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #b66d0b;
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #FF980F;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-6 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 2px;
  width: 60px;
}
.model-6 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #bbb;
  top: -16px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-6 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #376fcb;
}
.model-6 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4285F4;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-7 .checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #555;
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  border-color: #329043;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-8 .checkbox label {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 95px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.model-8 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-8 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #FF980F;
}
.model-8 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 35px;
}

.model-9 .checkbox label {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 90px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.model-9 .checkbox label:after {
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-9 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #266c33;
}
.model-9 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #369a48;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-10 .checkbox:after {
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.model-10 .checkbox:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-10 .checkbox label {
  width: 80px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.model-10 .checkbox label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-10 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-10 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-11 .checkbox:after, .model-11 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #90201F;
}
.model-11 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #266c33;
}
.model-11 .checkbox label {
  background: #E3666C;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.model-11 .checkbox label:after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  *zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF');
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 30%, #dddddd 45%, #ffffff 50%, #dddddd 55%, #ffffff 70%);
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: 0.1s;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-11 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-11 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-12 .checkbox {
  background: #2B2B2D;
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox:after, .model-12 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  height: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label:after {
  background-color: #3F4545;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJvYmplY3RCb3VuZGluZ0JveCIgeDE9IjAuNSIgeTE9IjAuMCIgeDI9IjAuNSIgeTI9IjEuMCI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzY2NjY2NiIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzNmNDU0NSIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666 0%, #3f4545 100%);
  top: -9px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background: #151515;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 7px;
  top: -2px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 45px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox input:checked + label:before {
  background: #94DA00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #94DA00;
  left: 52px;
}

.model-13 .checkbox:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  color: #666;
  top: 12px;
  right: 15px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #777;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox label:after {
  content: 'ON';
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-indent: 100px;
  background: #777;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 14px;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  top: 3px;
  left: auto;
  right: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  border-color: #329043;
}
.model-13 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: auto;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.4s, 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  width: 80px;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.model-14 .checkbox:after, .model-14 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #90201F;
}
.model-14 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #266c33;
}
.model-14 .checkbox label {
  background: #fff;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.model-14 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #90201F;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-14 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4BD865;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-15 .checkbox {
  width: 94px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  background: #266c33;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.model-15 .checkbox:after, .model-15 .checkbox label:before {
  content: 'ON';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  left: auto;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label {
  background: #f00;
  width: 90px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label:after {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-15 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  transform: translateX(40px);
}
.model-15 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}


/* Banner*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
.open3 {
  display: block;
}



/* SecondBanner */
html1,
body1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
.open1 {
  display: block;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- First -->
    <div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
<div class="exponea-count3">

Want To Switch Website View?
<div class="model-7">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>



  </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you run the above code, see how the toggle button is aligned below the `Want To Switch Website View?` line? I do not want that and instead, the button should be beside the text and not under it.

### Expected Output

The toggle button should be beside the `Want To Switch Website View?` text. Beside means that the button should appear after the text but beside it.

Expected Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leAGL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

section {
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
}

/*=====================*/
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox:after, .checkbox:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  -webkit-font-kerning: auto;
          font-kerning: auto;
  font-language-override: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-synthesis: weight style;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
}
.checkbox label {
  width: 90px;
  height: 42px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 46px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox input:hover + label:after {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-1 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #376fcb;
}
.model-1 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4285F4;
}

.model-2 .checkbox label {
  width: 75px;
}
.model-2 .checkbox label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-2 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-2 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 35px;
}

.model-3 .checkbox label {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 38px;
}
.model-3 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #bbb;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.model-3 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: 55px;
}

.model-4 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 25px;
  width: 75px;
}
.model-4 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  top: -8px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}
.model-4 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #77C2BB;
}
.model-4 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #009688;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-5 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 15px;
  width: 85px;
}
.model-5 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  top: -12px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:hover + label:after {
  transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #b66d0b;
}
.model-5 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #FF980F;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-6 .checkbox label {
  background: #bbb;
  height: 2px;
  width: 60px;
}
.model-6 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #bbb;
  top: -16px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-6 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #376fcb;
}
.model-6 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4285F4;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-7 .checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 5px solid #555;
  height: 42px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #555;
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  border-color: #329043;
}
.model-7 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-8 .checkbox label {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 95px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.model-8 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-8 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #FF980F;
}
.model-8 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 35px;
}

.model-9 .checkbox label {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 90px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.model-9 .checkbox label:after {
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-9 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #266c33;
}
.model-9 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #369a48;
  left: 40px;
}

.model-10 .checkbox:after {
  content: '\f00d';
  color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.model-10 .checkbox:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-10 .checkbox label {
  width: 80px;
  background: #EAEAEA;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.model-10 .checkbox label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
.model-10 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-10 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-11 .checkbox:after, .model-11 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #90201F;
}
.model-11 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #266c33;
}
.model-11 .checkbox label {
  background: #E3666C;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.model-11 .checkbox label:after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  *zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF');
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 30%, #dddddd 45%, #ffffff 50%, #dddddd 55%, #ffffff 70%);
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: 0.1s;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-11 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  background: #4BD865;
}
.model-11 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 40px;
}

.model-12 .checkbox {
  background: #2B2B2D;
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox:after, .model-12 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  height: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label:after {
  background-color: #3F4545;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJvYmplY3RCb3VuZGluZ0JveCIgeDE9IjAuNSIgeTE9IjAuMCIgeDI9IjAuNSIgeTI9IjEuMCI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzY2NjY2NiIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzNmNDU0NSIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666 0%, #3f4545 100%);
  top: -9px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  background: #151515;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 7px;
  top: -2px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 45px;
}
.model-12 .checkbox input:checked + label:before {
  background: #94DA00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #94DA00;
  left: 52px;
}

.model-13 .checkbox:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  color: #666;
  top: 12px;
  right: 15px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox label {
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #777;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox label:after {
  content: 'ON';
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-indent: 100px;
  background: #777;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 14px;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.2s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.4s linear;
  top: 3px;
  left: auto;
  right: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
}
.model-13 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  border-color: #329043;
}
.model-13 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #3fb454;
  left: auto;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.4s, 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s, width 0.2s linear 0.4s, text-indent 0.3s linear 0.4s;
  width: 80px;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.model-14 .checkbox:after, .model-14 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #90201F;
}
.model-14 .checkbox:before {
  content: 'ON';
  left: -40px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #266c33;
}
.model-14 .checkbox label {
  background: #fff;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.model-14 .checkbox label:after {
  background: #90201F;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-14 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  background: #4BD865;
  left: 50px;
}

.model-15 .checkbox {
  width: 94px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  background: #266c33;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.model-15 .checkbox:after, .model-15 .checkbox label:before {
  content: 'ON';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 8px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label:before {
  content: 'OFF';
  left: auto;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label {
  background: #f00;
  width: 90px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.model-15 .checkbox label:after {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 32px;
}
.model-15 .checkbox input:checked + label {
  transform: translateX(40px);
}
.model-15 .checkbox input:checked + label:after {
  left: 0;
}


/* Banner*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
.open3 {
  display: block;
}



/* SecondBanner */
html1,
body1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
.open1 {
  display: block;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- First -->
    <div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
<div class="exponea-count3">

Want To Switch Website View?
<div class="model-7">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>



  </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>





<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be more usefull if you explained how you solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS-Code:

```
.model-7 {
  float: right;
}
```

if you want to align it vertically then add this to your CSS-Code:

```
.exponea-count3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the text to a child div so the text and the toggle button are two separate elements in one div. Then set the parent div display to 'flex'. I hope I managed to help :)

Comment: This answer would be more helpful with a minimal example.